How to use React-Hook-Form to control two fields which depend on each other?
I want to create a form with two MUI Select components. Conference and division are inter-related. Their relationships are described below.

There is a conference corresponding to each division, as shown in the teams array. When a division is selected, the corresponding conference will be automatically selected.

There are 3 divisions in each conference, as shown in the teams array. When a conference is selected, the divisions list will be filtered to include divisions corresponding to that conference, e.g. if Western is selected, the divisions list only includes NorthWest, Pacific and SouthWest.


const teams = [
    {
        "conference": "Eastern",
        "division": "Atlantic"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Eastern",
        "division": "Central"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Eastern",
        "division": "Southeast"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Western",
        "division": "Northwest"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Western",
        "division": "Pacific"
    },
    {
        "conference": "Western",
        "division": "Southwest"
    }
]

export default function Demo() {
    const [conference, setConference] = useState("Western");
    const [division, setDivision] = useState("Pacific");
    const [divisions, setDivisions] = useState([...new Set(teams.map(obj => obj.division))]);

    const handleConferenceChange = event => {
        setConference(event.target.value);
        setDivision("");
        setDivisions(teams.filter(obj => obj.conference === event.target.value).map(item => item.division));
    }

    const handleDivisionChange = event => {
        setDivision(event.target.value);
        setConference(teams.find(obj => obj.division === event.target.value)?.conference);
    }

    const { control } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            conference: "",
            division: ""
        }
    })

    return (
        <form>
            <Grid container columnSpacing={4}>
                <Grid xs={6}>
                    <Typography sx={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Conference</Typography>
                    <Controller
                        name='conference'
                        control={control}
                        render={({field}) => (
                            <Select
                                {...field}
                                fullWidth
                            >
                                {[...new Set(teams.map(obj => obj.conference))].map((conference, index) => <MenuItem key={index} value={conference}>{conference}</MenuItem>)}
                            </Select>
                        )}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid xs={6}>
                    <Typography sx={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Division</Typography>
                    <Controller
                        name='division'
                        control={control}
                        render={({field}) => (
                            <Select
                                {...field}
                                fullWidth
                                displayEmpty
                                renderValue={selected => selected?.length === 0 ? <span>-- Select --</span> : selected}
                            >
                                {divisions.map((division, index) => <MenuItem key={index} value={division}>{division}</MenuItem>)}
                            </Select>
                        )}
                    />
                </Grid>                
            </Grid>
        </form>
    )
}

I've studied the react-hook-form documentation and searched some tutorials on YouTube. None of them cover my use case. Could someone please teach me how my use case can be implemented using react-hook-form?

The code you have provided does not implement react-hook-form.  Can you show how you have attempted to implement react-hook-form?

@Scott Z, I've updated my codes and I don't know how to use react-hook-form to track and change the state of each components.

You're still setting state in the onChange handlers.  With react-hook-form you don't usually need to track field values with local state.
In react hook form useForm returns a watch property which can be used to track values of specific fields. https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch
React Hook Form also has a useWatch api specifically designed to subscribe to value changes of specific fields. https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usewatch
React hook form also provides a context api for your form so you can deeply nest components, and still have easy access to all of the properties of useForm https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useformcontext
Combining these APIs together you could create controlled inputs/selects/etc that rely on form context to handle their watche states.  A nice thing about using formContext is that useWatch and useController are already wired to work with formContext so you don't have to pass control to those hooks if they are used inside of formContext.
Also, defaultValues should represent the names of the fields.  You are passing in a default value for select but you don't have field named select.  Your field names are conference and division, so your default values should look like {conference:"", division:""}

thank you so much for your reply. I've updated my codes and removed value and onChange props for the conference and division fields. However, after studying the documentation, I find it hard to understand the example codes in the documentation and I don't know how to apply useWatch and useFormContext api in my codes. Would you please provide a codesandbox demonstrating how relevant api can be applied in my codes?
